# Performance anomaly in ruby Set.include? with symbols (2.2.2 vs 2.1.6)

Tags: ruby, performance

While benchmarking some code to find out, if using a set is really faster than array when checking for elements included via include? I found some performance anomaly regarding strings and symbols inside the collection.

First the script I used for benchmarking. It basically creates an array containing 50 random 50 character strings, gets a sample of 20 and checks if all the sample values are included. The same data is used to create an set of strings, an array of symbols and a set of symbols.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'
require 'Set'

collection_size = 50
element_length = 50
sample_size = 20

Benchmark.ips do |x|

  array_of_strings = begin
    (1..collection_size).map {|pos| (0..element_length).map { ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join }
  end
  array_of_symbols = array_of_strings.map(&:to_sym)
  set_of_strings = Set.new(array_of_strings)
  set_of_symbols = Set.new(array_of_symbols)

  sample_of_strings = array_of_strings.sample(sample_size)
  sample_of_symbols = array_of_symbols.sample(sample_size)

  x.report("array_of_strings: #{collection_size} elements with length #{element_length}, sample size #{sample_of_strings.length}") {
    sample_of_strings.each do |s|
      array_of_strings.include? s
    end
  }

  x.report("set_of_strings: #{collection_size} elements with length #{element_length}, sample size #{sample_of_strings.length}") {
    sample_of_strings.each do |s|
      set_of_strings.include? s
    end
  }

  x.report("array_of_symbols: #{collection_size} elements with length #{element_length}, sample size #{sample_of_symbols.length}") {
    sample_of_symbols.each do |s|
      array_of_symbols.include? s
    end
  }

  x.report("set_of_symbols: #{collection_size} elements with length #{element_length}, sample size #{sample_of_symbols.length}") {
    sample_of_symbols.each do |s|
      set_of_symbols.include? s
    end
  }

  x.compare!  
end
```

Test system was a 2011 Macbook Pro, running OSX 10.10.4, both ruby version were installed using rvm 1.26.11.

When executing this with ruby 2.2.2, I got the following results:

```
set_of_strings:      145878.6 i/s
set_of_symbols:      100100.1 i/s - 1.46x slower
array_of_symbols:    81680.0 i/s - 1.79x slower
array_of_strings:    43545.9 i/s - 3.35x slower
```

As expected, the set is faster than array, even so not as fast as I expected. What struck me strange was, that the set containing strings was faster than the one containing symbols, while for arrays the symbol one was much faster. I repeated the script multiple times and the ratio stayed the same.

To get more insights, I ran the benchmark script with ruby 2.1.6 and got those results:

```
set_of_symbols:      202362.3 i/s
set_of_strings:      145844.1 i/s - 1.39x slower
array_of_symbols:    39158.1 i/s - 5.17x slower
array_of_strings:    24687.8 i/s - 8.20x slower
```

Again sets are faster than arrays, but the array performance is much worse than in ruby 2.2.2, seems performance improvement went very well compared to 2.1.6 for that cases.

The odd thing is the result of the sets. The set containing strings reaches about the same instructions per second in ruby 2.2.2 and 2.1.6., which is how it should be. But the set containing symbols is **twice as fast** in ruby 2.1.6. than it is in 2.2.2!

I also varied the parameters for the benchmark script and the results stay the same. Sets with strings reach about the same i/s in 2.1.6 and 2.2.2, while sets of symbols are much slower in 2.2.2.

My questions are now

- can anyone explain this behavior?
- is there anything I overlooked in my benchmarking script?
- if others can reproduce this, how should this be reported to ruby developers?

**Update 1:**

Seems the underlying problem is Hash class itself, that is used for storing values in Set class. Just created a hash with numbers of 1 to 1000 as string/symbol keys and did Hash[k] access with a sample.

Ruby 2.2.2:

```
h_string: 1000 keys, sample size 200:    29374.4 i/s
h_symbol: 1000 keys, sample size 200:    10604.7 i/s - 2.77x slower
```

Ruby 2.1.6.:

```
h_symbol: 1000 keys, sample size 200:    31561.9 i/s
h_string: 1000 keys, sample size 200:    25589.7 i/s - 1.23x slower
```

For some reason, using symbols as Hash keys is much slower in 2.2.2, benchmarking script used:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

collection_size = 1000
sample_size = 200

Benchmark.ips do |x|

  h_string = Hash.new 
  h_symbol = Hash.new

  (1..collection_size).each {|k| h_string[k.to_s] = 1}
  (1..collection_size).each {|k| h_symbol[k.to_s.to_sym] = 1}

  sample_of_string_keys = h_string.keys.sample(sample_size)
  sample_of_symbol_keys = sample_of_string_keys.map(&:to_sym)

  x.report("h_string: #{collection_size} keys, sample size #{sample_of_string_keys.length}") {
    sample_of_string_keys.each do |s|
      h_string[s]
    end
  }

  x.report("h_symbol: #{collection_size} keys, sample size #{sample_of_symbol_keys.length}") {
    sample_of_symbol_keys.each do |s|
      h_symbol[s]
    end
  }

  x.compare!  
end
```

**Update 2:**

I repeated the tests with latest `ruby 2.3.0dev (2015-07-26 trunk 51391) [x86_64-darwin14]` and there the set with symbols is much faster again and for small collection_size and sample_size on one level with ruby 2.1.6

For bigger numbers like a Hash with 10000 values and checking 100 samples, ruby 2.1.6 reaches about double the iterations of ruby-head (and nearly 3 times those of ruby 2.2.2). So it seems some improvements were going on in ruby-head, but still not enough to get back to old performance.

**Update 3:**

Thanks to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631284/performance-anomaly-in-ruby-set-include-with-symbols-2-2-2-vs-2-1-6?noredirect=1#comment51218588_31631284) by @cremno I rechecked my initial set benchmark with the 2.2 branch and there 2.2 is on the same level as 2.1.6

My conclusions for now

- always benchmark your actual code and also think about if the difference is really visible. In my use case, even so that kind of check is done about 50 times per web request, the overall time difference is only a fraction of a millisecond
- ruby 2.3 and backported code in hopefully upcoming 2.2.3 seem to get faster again with symbols in Hashes
- don't make assumptions like 'symbols are always faster' or 'Set.include? is always faster than Array.include?'
- Symbol Garbage Collection comes with a big [performance penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631284/performance-anomaly-in-ruby-set-include-with-symbols-2-2-2-vs-2-1-6#comment51220547_31631284), if you handle really big Hashes.

Comment: To answer your questions, Yes, probably, and as per reporting guidelines as posted.  This is probably better as a blog post, rather than a SO post.  Do you have a problem you are trying to solve?  There are some blog posts out there that talk about the differences when using strings and symbols and how those allocations effect performance, and even when.

Comment: The fixed comparison point of strings length 50 and collection size 50 may be giving you a limited picture. Although clearly something has changed between Ruby versions, the differences in relative performance may be more complex than your single sample point wrt to those two params implies.

Comment: The single biggest version between 2.1 and 2.2 in this area is that symbols are now garbage collectable

Comment: @NeilSlater I checked also other values, e.g. 50000 elements with length 10 and sample of 1000. Set of strings is 2572.6 i/s (2.1.6) vs. 2709.9 i/s (2.2.2) and set of symbols is 3931.3 i/s (2.1.6) vs 1659.5 i/s (2.2.2). And also for very small values (10 elements length 10 and sample of 2), string set performs about the same and symbol set is much slower in 2.2.2

Comment: @vgoff I don't have a real problem, in my use case, the difference is so small in overall time needed for those include? checks, that I wouldn't see a real difference. Just wondered about the big difference in benchmarks.

Comment: No clue, good question ;) Generally savings are achieved when using symbols by not allocating objects i.e. 1000.times { :foo } will beat running the same code with "foo". In this case we're not allocating any objects in the test section. Still doesn't explain why string is so much faster in these tests. I'm curious myself, i'll keep playing.

Comment: Can you try `ruby_2_2` (the 2.2 branch)? See [Bug #11035](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11035) (2.3 and backported to 2.2 however not part of a release yet). There's also [Misc #10278](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10278) which might be another cause of the improvement in 2.3.

Comment: @cremno I tried it out, got `ruby 2.2.3p147 (2015-07-04 revision 51143) [x86_64-darwin14]` compiled from that branch. Performance in my tests is about the same as with ruby_head. But as with 2.3, if your hash gets bigger (i.e. thousands of symbol keys) and you have to check many keys (i.e. hundreds), 2.1.6 is still way faster. In a rather extreme check with a hash containing 200_000 keys and doing 10_000 lookups, 2.1.6 got nearly 6x the i/s than 2.2.3 (480 i/s vs. 85 i/s). For string keys, there's is not real difference with >=2.2.x being a bit faster than 2.1.6.

Comment: @BrunoE.: Another thing you could try is disabling the (dynamic) symbol GC (mentioned by @FrederickCheung). Either add `-DUSE_SYMBOL_GC=0` to `CFLAGS` or directly edit `internal.h` (change the 1 into a 0). That might help with the performance.

Comment: @cremno good idea, I set it to 0 in internal.h and now 2.2.3 went from 85 i/s to 620 i/s and that is even faster than 2.1.6. So it seems symbol garbage collection has a big impact in the case of really big hashes.

Comment: @BrunoE. Good find. Care to report about the issue on [Ruby Issue Tracking System](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/issues) ?

Comment: @DavidUnric filed https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11396 for it

Comment: @BrunoE. Thanks. Also like to see how it has been immediately fixed. Good work from Ruby devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an performance issue in the ruby code, which was fixed really fast :-)

Issue: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11396
Commit: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/442b77e72166c9c993e3c6663568431123510dec

Comment: Great job reporting that. I wonder if it would be possible to add a rubybench.org benchmark to prevent a regression like this from happening again.

Comment: There were some benchmarks added to ruby itself: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/cb87005f6966b334cc8cacc0d3dcd082b4cad569 How do these relate to rubybench.org?

Comment: That should be good. Just wanted to make sure if there was a regression it would be noticed.